# Can I take my XP and FCC from FIFA 15 to FIFA 17?

Tags: pc, origin, fifa-15, fifa-17

I've played a lot of FIFA 15 on PC and still sometimes do so, and I have a pretty high level. That level was taken over from FIFA 14, and so was the *currency* called FCC. That made it possible to buy a lot of the offline stuff, like new balls, kits and celebrations early on in the new game.

Is this also possible from FIFA 15 to FIFA 17? I've skipped FIFA 16 and am considering to go directly to FIFA 17. Both games (as well as the 14) would be linked to the same Origin account.

Comment: Generally this type of transfers are only between direct sequels. I'm not sure if that's the case with FIFA , but most likely it's not possible to "skip" one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

I bought FIFA 17 on discount and it welcomed me back on level 71 and remembered my club.